# Некорректная работа curl на ubuntu. Проблема с http1.1, tls1.3

Tags: http, curl, tls

curl реализует странное поведение для ubuntu 18.04. При этом, корректно работает на macos. В чём проблема?

## Ubuntu

При запросе с ubuntu:

```
curl https://market.yandex.ru
```

Я получаю 403 ошибку. Если же сделать `-q --tlsv1.3 --http1.1`, то всё корректно работает:

```
curl -q --tlsv1.3 --http1.1 https://market.yandex.ru
```

Стоит отметить, что флаг `-v` говорит о том, что запрос

```
curl -v https://market.yandex.ru
```

использует tlsv1.3 и http1.1. Но в реальности, видимо, это не так. Также отмечу, что `curl --version` выдаёт:

```
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1b zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0
```

## Mac OS

При запросе с macOS, я получаю корректный ответ. Не нужно никакого флага про tls, http:

```
curl https://market.yandex.ru
```

Также отличаются версии пакетов:

```
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
```

## Вопрос

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Круто, что у тебя есть макбучек но это не сильно относится к делу. Переходи по ссылке https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html и смотри, что произошло между этими двумя версиями. Можешь нажать ctrl+f, вставить в строку поиска 'http1' и нажать ентер

Comment: @СергейВалерьевич это не у меня, а доброго человека, который увидел, что не воспроизводится проблема на маке.